# How to use a memory card?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, storage

I've recently bought an android phone with only about 2GB memory. After this, I bought a 8GB memory card and it was inserted into the phone.

How to control which data is stored in the phone itself and which in the memory card?

Probably I need all data to be stored in the card in order for the small internal memory not to overflow. How to do it?

Comment: Depending on the Android version, the external SD card is only used if either the app supports this (nearly no app at all except camera apps) or you move data there manually. On Android 2.x the SD card is used correctly as "external storage", after that the internal one is used as "external storage".